# Fuzzy and proximity search together in Azure search

Tags: lucene, azure-cognitive-search

Need help with the query to combine proximity search and fuzzy search in Azure. Index has items below:

1. University of Washington
2. University of Mary Washington Foundation
3. Washington Adventist University

Search term: 
Universty of Washington - (University misspelled)

This should return record 1. i.e Fuzzy matching on University and Proximity match on rest of the words.

Answer (score 2):

From the Azure Search documentation:

[Fuzzy Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search#bkmk_fuzzy)

> To do a fuzzy search, use the tilde "~" symbol at the end of a single word with an optional parameter, a number between 0 and 2 (default), that specifies the edit distance. For example, "blue~" or "blue~1" would return "blue", "blues", and "glue".

[Proximity Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search#bkmk_proximity)

> Insert a tilde "~" symbol at the end of a phrase followed by the number of words that create the proximity boundary. For example, "hotel airport"~5 will find the terms "hotel" and "airport" within 5 words of each other in a document.

Based on this documentation, I can construct a query that combines fuzzy and proximity search

```
“Universty~ of~ Washington~”~5
```

Note that you must use [Lucene query syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search#example-showing-full-syntax) for this to work

Comment: @mathew Do you actually have this working? In our tests, combining the syntax of both fuzzy and proximity does not work.

Comment: @PaulFleming Did you get it to work, how did you do this?

Comment: The given example doesn't seem to work from SOLR

Answer (score 0):

rachel~ ray~ cookware~1

Please try this fuzzy search with Edit distance 1. working

Comment: wild card search will work for misspelled search Say for example uni* of* Was*. This will fetch every word that matches first 3 characters